# Javascript recursion function that takes an argument n and recursively reduces it and stores the value of each in an array until it reaches 1

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have defined a function called countdown with one parameter (n). The function should use recursion to return an array containing the integers n through 1 based on the n parameter. If the function is called with a number less than 1, the function should return an empty array. For example, calling this function with n = 5 should return the array [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. Your function must use recursion by calling itself and must not use loops of any kind.

```
function countdown(n){
    if (n < 1){
        return [];
    }else{
        const countArray = countdown(n - 1);
        countArray.push(n);
        return countArray;
    }
 }
```

I am getting the following errors:
countdown(10) should return [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
countdown(5) should return [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Global variables should not be used to cache the array.

Comment: What does your code produce? Why does it produce that? What could you obviously do to fix it? Hint: do not *a*ppend but *pre*pend `n`.

Comment: @luk2302 or push before the recursive call

Comment: @Pointy That would require an additional parameter or a nested function though, which is probably not what the exercise is looking for

Comment: @Pointy how? You do not have an array before the recursive call (in the current setup)

Comment: Yea sorry. In a case like this I would usually nest the *real* function inside the outer one.

Comment: I should first declare an array to store the vaues of n or

Answer (score 0):

You could use an optional argument to pass the result array into the recursive calls:

```js
function countdown(n, arr = []){
  return n < 1 ? arr : arr.push(n) && countdown(n - 1, arr);
}

console.log(...countdown(10));
```

The spread is slooooow:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000">

const count=1000;

// @benchmark spread/iterator (Dabrowski)
{
  function countdown(n) {
      const arr = [n];
      if( n > 1) arr.push( ...countdown(n-1));
      return arr;
  }
  countdown(count);
}

// @benchmark recursion (Alexander)
{
  function countdown(n, arr = []){
    return n < 1 ? arr : arr.push(n) && countdown(n - 1, arr);
  }
  countdown(count);
}

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Noticed you copied my answer there for your benchmark. Quite a difference.

Comment: @Dabrowski added authors for clarity

Answer (score 0):

This works using the spread operator.

```
function countdown(n) {
    const arr = [];
    if( n > 1) arr.push( n, ...countdown(n-1));
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways of going about this... here is just one:

Here: I've used the following:

- recursion
- [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return []
  } else {
    return [n, ...countdown(n - 1)]
  }
}
console.log(countdown(5));
```

The spread operator unpacks elements of iterable objects such as arrays, sets, and maps into a list.
So  the line

```js
  return [n, ...countdown(n - 1)]
```

If we step through an example like `countdown(2)` it would look like this:

```js
  // n = 2
  return [2, ...countdown(1)]
  // countdown(1) evaluates to [1]
  // meaning it looks like:
  // return [2, ...[1]]
  // which is: [2, 1]
```

```js
  // n = 1
  return [1, ...countdown(0)]
  // countdown(0) evaluates to []
  // meaning it looks like:
  // return [1, ...[]]
  // which is: [1] (because `[]` is empty)
```